# Calling External Model Methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I have a two models, `A` and `B` where `A` `has_many` `B`.

In the `A` model, I have a public method that loops through all of the associated `B` objects and updates database fields in each of them. I would like to have the methods in `B` and run just the loops in `A`, but they do not appear to be saving correctly. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Here's an example of the methods:

```
def update_fields # A Method
  self.b.each do |b|
    b.b_method
  end
end

def b_method # B Method
  self.field = '5'
  self.save
end
```

Running this type of code, nothing is saved to the database and the output isn't updated.

How can I accomplish this type of thing? Or, does all the logic need to be in the `A` controller, even though it's dealing with `B` fields?

Comment: You might just double check that the `save` isn't returning `false`. If it is, it could just be some validations failing. There's certainly nothing wrong with the general approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with the validations, so the general approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

if a belongs_to b then a has only one b - so it doesn't make sense, that you try to iterate through multiple b in the a-method.

EDIT

you don't need "self." if you call instant methods. self is used to declare class methods.

but what confuses me the most, is, that you try to save something in a model. that belongs into a controller!

Comment: Using self is benign, since Ruby treats them the same, but just to see, I removed it and nothing happened. Also, nothing in this case is being saved from a form field, it's a JSON update that needs to be regularly made via a Rake task. That's why it's in the model instead of a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try using update_attributes

```
def update_fields
  b.each { |x| x.update_attributes(field: "5") }
end
```

Or

```
def b_method
  update_attributes(field: "5")
end
```

Comment: I tried update_attributes and nothing changed. I did, however, move all of the logic over into the `B` model and it worked without a hitch, so it leads me to believe that `save` isn't the problem.